# psql file path encoding error on Windows 10 when trying to \copy

Tags: postgresql, windows, csv, encoding

Installed the latest version of PostgreSQL on my Windows 10 machine. Created this SQL query to copy data from csv to table:

```
COPY schema.table(column1, column2)
FROM 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\cyrillic name\cyrillic name.csv'
DELIMITER ',';
```

Executed it in DataGrip and got this:

```
[58P01] ERROR: could not open file "C:\Users\User\Desktop\cyrillic name\cyrillic name.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
```

At the same time if I put this file in 'C:\Users\Public\Postgres\English name.csv', then everything runs perfectly fine.
Network service has total control over the cyrillic directory and the file (changed it after I got "Permission denied" when file was under fully english path in my desktop folder (C:\Users\User\Desktop)).
Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858856/postgresql-copy-command-error) answer and decided to use \copy in psql:

```
postgres-# cmd.exe /c chcp 1252
postgres-# \COPY schema.table(column1, column2) FROM 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\cyrillic name\cyrillic name.csv' DELIMITER ',';
```

But it didn't work, also tried other encodings - it always returns the same result:

```
C:/Users/User/Desktop/some weird symbolic mess/some weird symbolic mess.csv: No such file or directory
```

It is for sure some weird issue with Windows encodings, is there a way to workaround this issue or the only way to solve this is to rename file path to full english?

Comment: This page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-ucoderef/28fefe92-d66c-4b03-90a9-97b473223d43 suggests that codepage 1251 might be better for Cyrillic, than 1252.  But I noticed that there are several that mention cyrillic, so ... try them one by one?

Comment: @GregHNZ tried 855, 866, 1251. The point is that the 'symbolic mess' stays exactly the same each time. I doubt that trying other ones will do anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't think that there is a solution for your problem. The path in the `COPY` statement is always in the database encoding, and if the operating system uses a different encoding, you are out of luck.

You could have created the database with the same encoding as the operating system, but anything other than UTF-8 is a bad choice. Perhaps you should switch to an operating system that has arrived in the 21st century and supports UTF-8.