# How PostgreSQL Copy command work on Windows?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-copy

I need to copy table data into text file on Windows in csv format. How to do that?

What I have tried:

```
COPY test TO '"E:\\test.csv"' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I am receiving an error while executing this query. That `test.csv` file have to create first before copying data into that.

> ERROR: relative path not allowed for COPY to file
>   SQL state: 42602

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130039/how-to-export-the-resulting-data-in-postgresql-to-csv

Comment: i have tried already but failed

Comment: You have both single and double quotes around your file path. Try removing the double quotes.

Comment: If it is remote server running on *nix OS then absolute Win path interpreted as relative on it.

Answer (score 2):

This will work providing you have permissions. It will put the csv file at the root directory of the same drive that Postgresql is installed on, probably C:

```
COPY test TO '\test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```